# openvpn does not recover from disabling redirect-gateway

Tags: openvpn, gateway

When I enable the redirect-gateway option on the server, restart openvpn, and restart the client software, the new default gateway is set on the client.

When I then disable the redirect-gateway option in the server config, restart openvpn on the server, then on the client, the client no longer sets the old gateway, effectively breaking access to the outside world.

Why could this be?

Comment: i dont think this is worth investigating, even if its a bug, as one doesnt change such an important option on the server every day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this depends on your configuration. Most likely you've included something like

user nobody
group nobody

in your client config. The side effect of this is that the client can not restore the old routes when the connection dies.

Without more information on your setup it is impossible to tell for sure.